# Nested lists: Append string in list to list before

Tags: python, python-3.x

as an exercise I want to try analyzing a Whatsapp chat of mine. I opened the .txt file, used `reader()` and `list()` on it and removed the blank lines/lists. The remaining lists have the following format: `chat = [[01.01.2019, 12:00 - name1: message1][message2] … ]`

I would like to take the lists that only contain messages (not date, time and name) and merge them with the list that came just before it.
This is how it should look like in the end:

`chat = [[01.01.2019, 12:00 - name1: message1 message2] … ]`

I tried the following loops where if the list begins not with a number, the content will be stored inside a variable, but none of them is appended and when the loop is done, the variable has the last instance of a message only list stored inside.

```
for row in chat:    # add to row before if no date in line
    row = list(row)
    without = ""
    if row[0].isalpha():
        without = row[0]
    else:
        row.append(without)
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. It's not clear what the input and output should look like.

Comment: `would like to append the lists with only a message inside to the complete lists which came before each of them but can't seem to figure out how.`  please clearly reword this, I do not know what this means

Comment: Oh, you want to handle multiline entries by concatenating with the previous line. I would make a generator and let it be an intermediary step.

Comment: @Hoog Yeah my bad, was a little confusing, I hope it's clearer now. I also edited the pseudocode lines.

Answer (score 1):

Take a complicated task, and break it up into different easy tasks.

This is an example of a generator that reads from a multi-line source, and outputs the actual lines you want, with some formatting to handle newlines.

```
# this is the condition from your code
def is_new_line(line):
    tokens = list(line)
    if tokens and not tokens[0].isalpha():
        return True
    return False

# this is a generator that takes multiline chats and outputs full rows without newlines
def line_generator(chat):
    row = []
    for line in chat:
        if is_new_line(line):
            if (row):
                yield ' '.join(row)
            row = [line.rstrip()]
        else:
            row.append(line.rstrip())
    if (row):
        yield ' '.join(row)

# sample data
chat = ['1 one\n', 'two\n', 'three\n', '2 one\n', 'two\n', 'three\n']

# the generator just outputs the rows as you want them defined
for row in line_generator(chat):
    print(row)
```

> 1 one two three
>   2 one two three

Comment: Repeated uses of `row += ...` is an inefficient way to build up a string value. Use `str.join` instead.

Comment: Interesting, I'll take advantage of that if it comes up again. Updated, but no change to the adaptor's interface.