# How to efficiently read the next line in a file

Tags: python

I have a text file as follows.

```
LA English
DT Article
GJ asthma; susceptible genes; natural language processing analysis; network
   centrality analysis
ID LITERATURE-BASED DISCOVERY; CO-WORD ANALYSIS; UNDISCOVERED PUBLIC
   KNOWLEDGE; INFORMATION-RETRIEVAL; FISH-OIL; SCIENTIFIC COLLABORATION;
   INSULIN-RESISTANCE; COMPLEX NETWORKS; METFORMIN; OBESITY
GJ natural language processing; network analysis
GJ data mining; text mining; learning analytics; deep learning;
   network centrality analysis
```

I want to get the entire row of `GJ` entry. i.e. my final output should be as follows.

```
[[asthma, susceptible genes, natural language processing analysis, network centrality analysis], [natural language processing, network analysis], [data mining, text mining, learning analytics, deep learning, network centrality analysis]]
```

I am using the following python programme.

```
with open(input_file, encoding="utf8") as fo:
    for line in fo:

        if line[:2].isupper():

            if line[:2] == 'GJ':
                temp_line = line[2:].strip()

                next_line = next(fo)

                if next_line[:2].isupper():
                    keywords = temp_line.split(';')
                else:
                    mykeywords = temp_keywords + ' ' + next_line.strip()
                    keywords = mykeywords.split(';')
                print(keywords)
```

However, there is a issue in the way I overlook the next line. Therefore, according to my programme, I do not get the third line of `GJ` (i.e. `[data mining, text mining, learning analytics, deep learning, network centrality analysis]`) as an output list.

I am happy to provide more details if needed.

Comment: If you are done processing the current line, __continue__ skips to the next iteration of the for loop. Consider writing a function for processing a line, in which case you would use __return__ instead of __continue__. If you mean time complexity, that's not changed unless you use a different file structure or metadata so that you know the offset of every line. WAIT, what is next(fo)? You already have a for loop. Let it do its job. You probably want __continue__ there, but you may need some state.

Comment: The biggest problem is that your 63 lines are not all upper-case and so it will never be found by your script.

Comment: A strategy that works well for these kinds of problems is to reframe it so that instead of trying to look ahead, you are instead looking back. For example, remember the last number you saw, and if you see a line without a number, use the remembered number instead.

Comment: This is fairly similar to another problem parsing multiline records. I recommended a helper function (generator actually) that pulls lines from the file and outputs full multi-line records https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55871622/nested-lists-append-string-in-list-to-list-before/55872116#55872116

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's try spliting the problem. There are two main logic processes in your code:

1. Extract each non-indented row with the following indented rows and join them as a single "line".
2. Filter "GJ" initial lines only.

Here is the code:

```python
def iter_lines(fo):
    cur_line = []
    for row in fo:
        if not row.startswith(' ') and cur_line:
            yield ' '.join(cur_line)
            cur_line = []  # reset the cache
        cur_line.append(row.strip())
    # yield the last line
    if cur_line:
        yield ' '.join(cur_line)


with open(input_file, encoding="utf8") as fo:
    for line in iter_lines(fo):
        if line.startswith('GJ'):
            keywords = [k.strip() for k in line[2:].split(';')]
            print(keywords)
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's what you are trying to do, and probably could have gotten there with a little debugging.

```
temp_keywords = ''
mykeywords = ''
with open(input_file, encoding="utf8") as fo:    
    for line in fo:
        if line[:2].isupper():    
            if line[:2] == 'GJ':
                temp_line = line[2:].strip()
                next_line = next(fo)
                temp_line += next_line.strip()
                print (temp_line.split(';'))
```

The problem here is that calling next(fo) yourself, instead of letting the for loop do its job, means you have to handle all of the for loop's job. So whatever you read into next_line will NOT be processed on the next loop. You will completely miss some lines of the file.

Instead, you always want to let the for loop handle its job.

But what you have here is two different methods of breaking a file up. It's easier to write a record parser which finds full records, and let it read lines from the file as needed. Here is an adaptation of my other answer linked in comments:

```
def is_new_record(line):
    return line[:2].isupper()

def helper(text):
    data = []
    for line in text.readlines():
        if is_new_record(line):
            if (data):
                yield ''.join(data)
            data = [line.strip()]
        else:
            data.append(line.strip())
    if (data):
        yield ''.join(data)

# the helper is a generator for multiline records, as one line
input_file = 'data.txt'
with open(input_file) as f:
    for record in helper(f):
        print (record)
```

> LA English
>   DT Article
>   GJ asthma; susceptible genes; natural language processing analysis; networkcentrality analysis
>   ID LITERATURE-BASED DISCOVERY; CO-WORD ANALYSIS; UNDISCOVERED PUBLICKNOWLEDGE; INFORMATION-RETRIEVAL; FISH-OIL; SCIENTIFIC COLLABORATION;INSULIN-RESISTANCE; COMPLEX NETWORKS; METFORMIN; OBESITY
>   GJ natural language processing; network analysis
>   GJ data mining; text mining; learning analytics; deep learning;network centrality analysis